# Floating point overflow

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I am getting floating point overflow error in this part of code. Can any of you guys help me to find out the reason.

```
do j=1,ny-1
  do i=1,nx-1

    sum = 0.0d0

    do k=0,1000
      n=2.0d0*dfloat(k)+ 1.0d0
      sum = sum + ((dsinh(n*pi*x(i))*dcos(n*pi*y(j)))/((n*n*pi*pi)*dsinh(2*n*pi)))
    end do

    ue(i,j)= (x(i)/(4.0d0))- 4.0d0*sum

  end do
end do
```

Comment: Some IMPLICIT NONE and an actual program may help. I woul dstart with an intermediate product of the stuff to the right of the sum = sum + . Then if/when k gets large, you may want to have sum be a double (*8) of the product is a float (*4). As SUM is an intrinsic, I would rename the 'sum'to MySum, or have an array dimension(0:1000) and use SUM(MySum). Why would you start the array at 0? 1001 points seems odd. The (n*pi*pi) and the (2*n*pi) and (n*pi) could be precomputed A, B and C, or parameters and then it is faster and look cleaner.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. You should show a complete program and describe how you are compiling it and show the actual output you are getting. Don't forget the input data. Be sure to read the help pages http://stackoverflow.com/tour http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please also take some effort to format your post and your code properly. I applied some basic indentation to your code.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the intermediate term `dsinh(2*n*pi)`. Consider `k=1000`. Then `n=2001` so we need to evaluate `dsinh(2001*pi)` which is about `0.5*exp(6286)` or over `10^2700`! This is far higher than any number  that can be represented in double precision. You need to reevaluate the the way you are calculating the sum. The term `dsinh(n*pi*x(i))` is problematic too.

My guess is that some sort of aysmptotic expansion is required for the robust evaluation of the quotient `dsinh(n*pi*x(i))/dsinh(2*n*pi)`. For `0<x(i)<2` this term should behave as `exp(n*pi*(x(i)-2))` as `n` becomes large. This is will be well behaved.